# URL.openStream generates en error (javax.net.ssl.SSLException)

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, lotus-domino

I've an issue, I'm using static Feed/URL (https) to read data from. Today it stopped to work. URL is still accessible and content is there. I see that feed/URL get new certificate recently.

```
URL page = new URL(url);
InputStream is = page.openStream(); // issue happens here
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Could somebody advise what should I check/test/do to resolve my issue?

Here is error StackTrace

```
Agent  error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 64
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:10)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:216)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:864)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:500)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:220)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:184)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:40)
Agent  error:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1207)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:66)
Agent  error:  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1022)
Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.getURLContent(JavaAgent.java:23)
Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:12)
Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Agent  error: Caused by: 
Agent  error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 64
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.crypto.provider.xc.a(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.crypto.provider.xc.a(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.crypto.provider.xc.a(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineGenerateKey(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(Unknown Source)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.b(kb.java:584)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:406)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:352)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:156)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:659)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:393)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:63)
Agent  error:  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:316)
Agent  error:  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Any update ? I get same error on a Domino java agent ;)  Certificate on source website was updated to. I have installed bouncyCastle workaround in my java.security file. (This was a good reference https://www.ineco.nl/ontwikkeling/sslexception-could-not-generate-dh-keypair/) But adding security.provider.10 seems to be the cause ?

Comment: @guilio yep. I will post my solution than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done 2 things about this issue:

- Up our Domino server. as far as I understand when you upgrade you Domino server it also upgrade certificate storage.
- We also disabled certificate validation (even though it's a dirty way).

You may try my solution [Disabling certificate validation in Java](https://dpastov.blogspot.dk/2014/04/disabling-certificate-validation-in-java.html)

Also have a look on related topics there, maybe it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the update. What version is your Domino server ? I'm still running 8.5.3.